# WebBrowser1 GetElement By name

Tags: vb.net

help use :

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("xxxx").SetAttribute("value", "TESTE")
```

but I don't have the id, I need to use the name

codigo:

```
<input class="InputElement is-complete Input" autocomplete="xxxx" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="xxx" inputmode="numeric" aria-label="xxxx" placeholder="xxxx" aria-placeholder="xxxx" aria-invalid="false" value="xxxx">
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? I'm not sure what name you're referring to. It would help a lot if you could show us the data you are using for a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i have this code in page:

<input class="InputElement is-complete Input" autocomplete="xxxx" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="xxx" inputmode="numeric" aria-label="xxxx" placeholder="xxxx" aria-placeholder="xxxx" aria-invalid="false" value="xxxx">

Comment: i need to make the webbrowser fill the field "xxx"
but I don't have the id, I just have this information
I was wondering how do I do this with the name

Answer (score 0):

Because more than one element can have the same name attribute, getElementsByName will return a node list of all elements with that name.

```
let x = document.getElementsByName("xxx");
```

This will set the "value" attribute for all elements with name "xxx".

```
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].SetAttribute("value", "TESTE");
}
```

---

Edit: Sorry I thought you were using javascript.
In VB.net something like this should work

```
Dim allElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

For Each Elem As HtmlElement In allElements

    If Elem.GetAttribute("name") = "codigo-date" Then

        Elem.SetAttribute("value", "TESTE)
  edit: Elem.SetAttribute("value", "TESTE")
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Brother, the "xxx" is a personification!
real code:


<input class="InputElement is-complete Input" autocomplete="codigo-exp" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="codigo-date" inputmode="numeric" aria-label="kofh" placeholder="MM / AA" aria-placeholder="MM / AA" aria-invalid="false" value="5578">

Comment: no error appeared, but did not fill in the fields in webbrowser
:(

Comment: I just noticed a syntax error ... i didn't close the  " " around TESTE .. try that

Comment: I corrected before adding to the code,  I believe it is not working because the page (site) has protection against VB.NET.
it will not let webbrowser add anything to the page!
is there any way to fix this?